# Recommended installation location for ASP.NET Core web apps

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, windows-installer

I have developed an ASP.NET Core web app that I would like to add to a Windows Installer package that already contains several desktop tools. The web app is built self-contained and of course contains many files. For that reason I zip all the files and the installer will only place the zip file in the installation directory (at least that is my current solution). Now I want to instruct the person installing the web app to extract the zip file and then configure IIS accordingly to run the web app. The question is:

Which directory should the web app be extracted to?

There are two options that immediately come to mind:

c:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWebApp

c:\Program Files\MyCompany\MySoftwarePackage\MyWebApp

Are there any recommendations for this choice?

I am not sure if there are special considerations 
regarding ASP.NET Core and the fact that IIS only
acts as a reverse proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuitive guess about `C:\inetpub` is close to the best answer.

Take the perspective of an admin who needs to maintain the system your package has been installed on. This admin is probably a generalist and will look in conventional locations for things.

As IIS web apps are already installed in `C:\inetpub` by default, this will be the place that most admins will expect to look first.

Additionally IIS is already permissioned to run from inetpub. This blanket security allowance means that any security applications or limitations for the system are already going to be focused on protecting the system from apps running from this folder.

Do not use wwwroot, however, as the default configuration of IIS allows this folder to be browseable on any unbound port 80 request to your server. Malicious people would need to know the exact path to files, but it is still a vulnerability.

`c:\inetput\myWebApp\` or `c:\inetput\myWebApp-80` or something similar is the right choice.

Comment: I would disagree.  I tend to pick [ProgramFilesFolder]Company\Product\WebSites\WebSite  and the admin can figure that out by looking at the install location in add/remove programs and the IIS admin console showing that the website/app/vdir has a document directory pointing back to there.  I've done it this way for years and no one has ever complained.  I've yet to install a product from Microsoft such as TFS  that installs directly to c:\inetpub.

Answer (score 1):

This is destined to be closed as opinionated, because frankly, there's no right answer. IIS can run a web app from any place; it doesn't matter. It must only have permissions to access the directory, which is there by default with `inetpub`, since IIS basically owns that, but would have to be added for any other location. However, creating a site and linking it to the directory will add the necessary permissions as well, so it's really pretty seamless, regardless. Long and short pick what ever you like, or you can leave it entirely up to the end user (which is actually probably the best bet).

Comment: Well I don't think it's opinionated because I'm actually looking for guidelines or best practices. Microsoft has given out guidelines for many other file system locations as well as Linux has very clear rules for the location of software, configuration, logs etc. But if it really doesn't matter, as you say, then that is an answer.